# Chocolatey unable to install jre. Throwing 1603

Tags: java, windows, powershell, windows-server-2016, chocolatey

I am unable to install jre in windows 2016 using chocolatey.
It throws an exit code 1603.

The jre is getting downloaded. The problem comes at the time of installing jre.

Following is the log:

```
[server-core-2016]  [0;32m    openstack: Progress: Downloading jre8 8.0.171... 100% [0m
[server-core-2016]  [0;32m    openstack: Progress: Downloading javaruntime 8.0.151... 100% [0m

[server-core-2016]  [0;32m    openstack: [0m
[server-core-2016]  [0;32m    openstack: jre8 v8.0.171 [Approved] [0m
[server-core-2016]  [0;32m    openstack: jre8 package files install completed. Performing other installation steps. [0m
[server-core-2016]  [0;32m    openstack: Searching if new version exists... [0m

[server-core-2016]  [0;32m    openstack: Downloading jre8 [0m
[server-core-2016]  [0;32m    openstack:   from 'https://javadl.oracle.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=233170_512cd62ec5174c3487ac17c61aaa89e8' [0m
[server-core-2016]  [0;32m    openstack: Progress: 100% - Completed download of C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\jre8\8.0.171\jre8Install.exe (61.66 MB). [0m
[server-core-2016]  [0;32m    openstack: Download of jre8Install.exe (61.66 MB) completed. [0m

[server-core-2016]  [0;32m    openstack: Hashes match. [0m
[server-core-2016]  [0;32m    openstack: Installing jre8... [0m

[server-core-2016]  [0;32m    openstack: WARNING: Generic MSI Error. This is a local environment error, not an issue with a package or the MSI itself - it could mean a pending reboot is necessary prior to install or something else (like the same version is already installed). Please see MSI log if available. If not, try again adding '--install-arguments="'/l*v c:\jre8_msi_install.log'"'. Then search the MSI Log for "Return Value 3" and look above that for the error. [0m
[server-core-2016]  [0;32m    openstack: ERROR: Running ["C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\jre8\8.0.171\jre8Install.exe" /s REBOOT=0 SPONSORS=0 AUTO_UPDATE=0  ] was not successful. Exit code was '1603'. Exit code indicates the following: Generic MSI Error. This is a local environment error, not an issue with a package or the MSI itself - it could mean a pending reboot is necessary prior to install or something else (like the same version is already installed). Please see MSI log if available. If not, try again adding '--install-arguments="'/l*v c:\jre8_msi_install.log'"'. Then search the MSI Log for "Return Value 3" and look above that for the error.. [0m
[server-core-2016]  [0;32m    openstack: Environment Vars (like PATH) have changed. Close/reopen your shell to [0m
[server-core-2016]  [0;32m    openstack:  see the changes (or in powershell/cmd.exe just type `refreshenv`). [0m
[server-core-2016]  [0;32m    openstack: The install of jre8 was NOT successful. [0m
[server-core-2016]  [0;32m    openstack: Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\jre8\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
```

Comment: So did you try what the log file suggested and run the install telling it to create an installation log?

Comment: It's a msi file.  Look at the log for `Return Code 3`.

Answer (score -1):

In the most recent versions of Chocolatey, there is more information about about the generic exit code that is 1603.  You can see this information in the log above:

> openstack: ERROR: Running ["C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\jre8\8.0.171\jre8Install.exe" /s REBOOT=0 SPONSORS=0 AUTO_UPDATE=0  ] was not successful. Exit code was '1603'. Exit code indicates the following: Generic MSI Error. This is a local environment error, not an issue with a package or the MSI itself - it could mean a pending reboot is necessary prior to install or something else (like the same version is already installed). Please see MSI log if available. If not, try again adding '--install-arguments="'/l*v c:\jre8_msi_install.log'"'. Then search the MSI Log for "Return Value 3" and look above that for the error.

The best recommendation would be to follow those instructions, as that is the best place to find the actual error message.